# Is there a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is bounded but not compact?

Tags: real-analysis

How to find a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is bounded but not compact. Does the open disk satisfies this?

Comment: In any Euclidean space, compact is the same as **closed** and bounded. If you want a noncompact set that is bounded, what can you conclude?

Answer (score 2):

The open unit disk
$$D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$$
is such a set. Indeed, it is covered by the open disks
$$U_n=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<(1-1/n)^2\},$$
of radius $1-1/n$, but there is no finite subcollection of $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ which covers $D$.

Comment: Doesn't $U_1$ cover the open disk?

Comment: @Nishant Thank you, I meant $1-1/n$. See edit.